# Apply WSO2 WSF/C++ into client based on Https Protocol

Tags: https, wso2

I establish a server using WCF based on Https protocol, now i want to create a client using WSO2 WSF/C++(and the client code is generated by Code Generator Tool), however, i can't communicate with server, because the client is based on Http, not Https. And i do not know how to code my client, also there is little sample or code for reference, almost of them are based on http. Now, how can i code my client to implement Https protocol.Does any one know how should i use the API? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since WSF/C++ uses Axis2/C, the HTTPS configurations are same for both WSF/C++ and Axis2/C. You can find HTTPS configuration [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/docs/axis2c_manual.html#ssl_client).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now i have done my configuration in my PC. When i build the source code of WSO2 WSF/C++, the error message dispaly:..\..\src\core\transport\http\sender\ssl\ssl_utils.c(65) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated. My configuration:Step 1.Add C:\OpenSSL\Lib & C:\OpenSSL\bin to Env path. Step 2: Add C:\OpenSSL to OPENSSL_BIN_DIR in file configure.in.